# population of select tag in struts

Tags: struts2

how to populate select tag using vector and object in struts2? The vector holds object which length is 3. like this

```
Vector vctData=new Vector();
Object[] objData=new Object[2];

objData[0]="IND";
objData[1]="India";
vctData.addElement(objData);

objData=new Object[2];
objData[0]="AMC";
objData[1]="America";
vctData.addElement(objData);

objData=new Object[2];
objData[0]="ENG";
objData[1]="England";
vctData.addElement(objData);
```

now i want to show this list in the select tag in struts2 where object's zeroth position is the key of the select and first position is the value of the select.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use Vector: use ArrayList; (Vector is legacy, and there are threadsafe alternatives too)
2. Don't use Object: create a real object, like "Country.java", with private variables like `countrCode` and `name`, and their getters and setters.
3. Declare your `List<Country> countries;` in the Action, load it in your `execute()` method, expose it through getter and setter;
4. in JSP, use:

   ```
   <s:select list = "countries" 
          listKey = "countryCode" 
        listValue = "name" 
             name = "selectedItem" />
   ```
5. enjoy a new era.